# Reading value from serial with c

Tags: c, serial-port

I am getting data from serial port that is :

```
i = 0   7e 126
i = 1   00 0
i = 2   02 2
i = 3   ffffff8a 4294967178
i = 4   03 3
i = 5   72 114
i = 6   7e 126
i = 7   00 0
i = 8   1d 29
i = 9   ffffff80 4294967168
i = 10   00 0
i = 11   7d 125
i = 12   33 51
i = 13   ffffffa2 4294967202
i = 14   00 0
i = 15   40 64
i = 16   ffffffc2 4294967234
i = 17   40 64
i = 18   30 48
i = 19   27 39
i = 20   00 0
i = 21   23 35
i = 22   32 50
i = 23   36 54
i = 24   2e 46
i = 25   31 49
i = 26   32 50
i = 27   23 35
i = 28   34 52
i = 29   33 51
i = 30   2e 46
i = 31   32 50
i = 32   31 49
i = 33   23 35
i = 34   30 48
i = 35   2e 46
i = 36   35 53
i = 37   36 54
i = 38   23 35
i = 39   ffffffeb 4294967275
i = 40   7e 126
i = 41   00 0
i = 42   02 2
i = 43   ffffff8a 4294967178
i = 44   03 3
i = 45   72 114
i = 46   00 0
i = 47   30 48
i = 48   30 48
i = 49   30 48
i = 50   30 48
i = 51   30 48
i = 52   30 48
i = 53   30 48
i = 54   30 48
i = 55   30 48
i = 56   30 48
i = 57   30 48
i = 58   30 48
i = 59   30 48
i = 60   30 48
i = 61   30 48
i = 62   30 48
i = 63   30 48
i = 64   30 48
i = 65   30 48
i = 66   30 48
i = 67   30 48
i = 68   30 48
i = 69   30 48
i = 70   30 48
i = 71   30 48
i = 72   30 48
i = 73   30 48
i = 74   30 48
i = 75   30 48
i = 76   30 48
i = 77   30 48
i = 78   30 48
i = 79   30 48
i = 80   30 48
i = 81   30 48
i = 82   30 48
i = 83   30 48
i = 84   30 48
i = 85   30 48
i = 86   30 48
i = 87   30 48
i = 88   30 48
i = 89   30 48
i = 90   30 48
i = 91   30 48
i = 92   30 48
i = 93   30 48
i = 94   30 48
i = 95   30 48
i = 96   30 48
i = 97   30 48
i = 98   30 48
i = 99   30 48
i = 100   30 48
i = 101   30 48
i = 102   30 48
i = 103   30 48
i = 104   30 48
i = 105   30 48
i = 106   30 48
i = 107   30 48
i = 108   30 48
i = 109   30 48
i = 110   30 48
i = 111   30 48
i = 112   30 48
i = 113   30 48
i = 114   30 48
i = 115   30 48
i = 116   30 48
i = 117   30 48
i = 118   30 48
i = 119   30 48
i = 120   30 48
i = 121   30 48
i = 122   30 48
i = 123   30 48
i = 124   30 48
i = 125   30 48
i = 126   30 48
i = 127   30 48
i = 128   30 48
i = 129   30 48
i = 130   30 48
i = 131   30 48
i = 132   30 48
i = 133   30 48
i = 134   30 48
i = 135   30 48
i = 136   30 48
i = 137   30 48
i = 138   30 48
i = 139   30 48
i = 140   30 48
i = 141   30 48
i = 142   30 48
i = 143   30 48
i = 144   30 48
i = 145   30 48
i = 146   30 48
i = 147   30 48
i = 148   30 48
i = 149   30 48
i = 150   30 48
i = 151   30 48
i = 152   30 48
i = 153   30 48
i = 154   30 48
i = 155   30 48
i = 156   30 48
i = 157   30 48
i = 158   30 48
i = 159   30 48
i = 160   30 48
i = 161   30 48
i = 162   30 48
i = 163   30 48
i = 164   30 48
i = 165   30 48
i = 166   30 48
i = 167   30 48
i = 168   30 48
i = 169   30 48
i = 170   30 48
i = 171   30 48
i = 172   30 48
i = 173   30 48
i = 174   30 48
i = 175   30 48
i = 176   30 48
i = 177   30 48
i = 178   30 48
i = 179   30 48
i = 180   30 48
i = 181   30 48
i = 182   30 48
i = 183   30 48
i = 184   30 48
i = 185   30 48
i = 186   30 48
i = 187   30 48
i = 188   30 48
i = 189   30 48
i = 190   30 48
i = 191   30 48
i = 192   30 48
i = 193   30 48
i = 194   30 48
i = 195   30 48
i = 196   30 48
i = 197   30 48
i = 198   30 48
i = 199   30 48
i = 200   30 48
i = 201   30 48
i = 202   30 48
i = 203   30 48
i = 204   30 48
i = 205   30 48
i = 206   30 48
i = 207   30 48
i = 208   30 48
i = 209   30 48
i = 210   30 48
i = 211   30 48
i = 212   30 48
i = 213   30 48
i = 214   30 48
i = 215   30 48
i = 216   30 48
i = 217   30 48
i = 218   30 48
i = 219   30 48
i = 220   30 48
i = 221   30 48
i = 222   30 48
i = 223   30 48
i = 224   30 48
i = 225   30 48
i = 226   30 48
i = 227   30 48
i = 228   30 48
i = 229   30 48
i = 230   30 48
i = 231   30 48
i = 232   30 48
i = 233   30 48
i = 234   30 48
i = 235   30 48
i = 236   30 48
i = 237   30 48
i = 238   30 48
i = 239   30 48
i = 240   30 48
i = 241   30 48
i = 242   30 48
i = 243   30 48
i = 244   30 48
i = 245   30 48
i = 246   30 48
i = 247   30 48
i = 248   30 48
i = 249   30 48
i = 250   30 48
i = 251   30 48
i = 252   30 48
i = 253   30 48
i = 254   30 48
```

It is a printed result of a buffer of 255. In this buffer 7e 126 is the start bit at i = 0. The end bit is 30 48 at 254 address of that buffer. Now I want to print from i = 24 to i = 40. This is my code for reading serial data :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
      #include <sys/stat.h>
      #include <fcntl.h>
      #include <termios.h>
      #include <stdio.h>

      #define BAUDRATE B115200
      #define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB1"
      #define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
      #define FALSE 0
      #define TRUE 1

      volatile int STOP=FALSE; 

      main()
      {
        int fd,c, res, i;
        struct termios oldtio,newtio;
        char buf[255];

        fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY ); 
        if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }

        tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current port settings */

        memset(&newtio,'0', sizeof(newtio));
        //bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
        newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
        newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
        newtio.c_oflag = 0;

        /* set input mode (non-canonical, no echo,...) */
        newtio.c_lflag = 0;

        //newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;   /* inter-character timer unused */
        //newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 5;   /* blocking read until 5 chars received */

        tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
        tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);

        int k = 7e 126;
    int m = 30 48;
        while (STOP==FALSE) {       /* loop for input */
          memset(buf,'0', 255);
          res = read(fd,buf,255);   /* returns after 5 chars have been input */
          buf[res]=0;               /* so we can printf... */
      //printf("%d", res);
          //printf(":%s:%d\n", buf, res);
          for(i = 0; i<255; i++)
    if(i[0] == k && i[254] == m)
    {
        for(i = 24; i<25; i++)
          printf("i = %d   %02x %u\n", i, buf[i], buf[i]);
    }
          //printf("");
          if (buf[0]=='z') STOP=TRUE;
        }

        tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
      }
```

This code is abled to print all value but can not compile after I was trying to print that specific range. Can someone please help me?

**EDIT**

```
serasync.c:22:42: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
         if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }
                                          ^
serasync.c:26:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’ [enabled by default]
         memset(&newtio,'0', sizeof(newtio));
         ^
serasync.c:41:17: error: exponent has no digits
         int k = 7e 126;
                 ^
serasync.c:41:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before numeric constant
         int k = 7e 126;
                    ^
serasync.c:42:13: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before numeric constant
  int m = 30 48;
             ^
serasync.c:50:6: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  if(i[0] == k && i[254] == m)
      ^
serasync.c:50:19: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  if(i[0] == k && i[254] == m)
```

Comment: Why couldn't it compile? What went wrong when you tried?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz see edit part for the error

Comment: `int k = 7e 126; int m = 30 48;` are syntax errors.

Comment: Just fix each error, starting with the first. Do you really find those messages so confusing? The first looks like a missing `#include` (Giveaway, it didn't know what `exit` meant. How should it have known?). The second looks like the same. The third is pretty obvious. What does "7e 126" mean anyway? Is that an integer? And so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
      for(i = 0; i<255; i++)
if(i[0] == k && i[254] == m)
```

Since `i` is an `int` and not an array or pointer, `i[0]` and `i[254]` don't make any sense. Maybe you meant `buf[i]`?

Bluntly, it just seems like you don't know C. Things like `int m = 30 48;` just don't make any sense at all. I can't even imagine what you think that means. What integer is "30 48"?

Comment: sorry char * will be, not int